# Navigation bar, border-bottom doesn't fill all

Tags: css, navigation, nav

So my problem is that, I have some vertical lines for every a tag in my li. And when I put in `border-bottom`, the line doesn't fill all of it; it lacks what looks like a pixel or two.

```
<div id="Nav_Bar">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li id="Forside">
                <a class="active <?php selected("index") ?>" href="../index.php">Forside</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="active <?php selected("sortiment") ?>" href="sortiment.php">Sortiment</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="active <?php selected("galleri") ?>" href="galleri.php">Galleri</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a class="active <?php selected("kontakt_view") ?>" href="kontakt_view.php">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div><!-- End of Nav_Bar -->

#Nav_Bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 1160px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 52px;
    margin-top: 156px;
    background-color: #fa8268;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -6px gray;
}

#Nav_Bar nav{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#Nav_Bar li {
    margin-top: 13px;
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

#Forside {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}

#Nav_Bar a {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#Nav_Bar a:hover {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#Nav_Bar a.Selected {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

How can I make it fill all the "li"?

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Yh2.png)

I have the fiddle link here. I managed to make the black line go from one verctial white line to the other, but when I try to put in some padding-bottom, to make the black line go down, it will give padding to the vertical line too, and I don't want that.

[Enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/nj1z2jcr/)

Answer (score 0):

You have this rule:

```
#Nav_Bar li {
    margin-top: 13px;
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
```

The `border-right: 1px solid white;`*is* a vertical line between the menu entries, so if you remove that, you probably get what you want.

A note: For better behaviour on hover you might want to change `display: inline;`to `display: inline-block;`

Comment: well, then it would help if you posted a js fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) or codepen (http://codepen.io/) where the behaviour you describe can be seen.

Comment: ah, you mean the black line at the bottom?

Comment: yea the black line in the bottom, i want that line to stretch from the left vertical white line til to the other vertical line. As you see in the picture i mass about one pixel.

Comment: make sure `#Nav_Bar li` has `padding-left: 0;` and `margin-left 0;`

Comment: just added the fiddle:) try also to put: padding-bottom: 12px; in #Nav_Bar li:hover. you will understand what I mean better. thanks :)

tried your tips, dosn't work.

Comment: well: your li element is actually less high than the nav bar (= the height of the vertical white lines) `padding-bottom: 12px;` in `#Nav_Bar li:hover` just changes that height for hover situations. Since both the white and the black lines are borders, they will allways join at the borders, no matter what you do. To change that , you'd have to use additional wrapper elements and javascript - a bit complicated...  (or 2 additional squares that cover the upper and lower parts of your (higher) white lines  (alos complicated...)

Answer (score 0):

The border will always be around the element (the `li` in this case) and borders always join at the corners.

So, instead of a bottom border, use a positioned pseudo-element (the parent `li` needs `position:relative`) and adjust the margin as required.

```
#Nav_Bar li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/nj1z2jcr/2/)